# Prove, that group of order $p^2$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, p-groups

I know there is a proof using these theorems:

- The center of a finite p−group is non-trivial
- For any group G ,
  $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic iff $G$ is abelian, or in otherwords: the quotient
  $G/Z(G)$ can never be non-trivial cyclic.

But is there a proof not using these theorems?

Comment: The only proof that I can think of contains essentially the same arguments as you would use in proving the two theorems you mention, so it more efficient to prove these theorems independently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is an element of order $p^2$, it's cyclic and thus abelian. Suppose there is no element element of order $p^2$. Then, the order of of the elements of $G$ are either $1$ or $p$. Let $h_1,h_2\in G$ two elements of order $p$ s.t. $h_2\notin\left<h_1\right>$. Then, $\left<h_1,h_2\right>$ is of order $p^2$ and is s.t. $|\left<h_1,h_2\right>|\geq p+1$. Therefore, $|\left<h_1,h_2\right>|=p^2$, and thus $G=\left<h_1,h_2\right>$. Therefore, $G$ is abelian.

We can show that $\left<h_i\right>$ are normal in $G$. Then, $[G:H_i]=p$ and thus $G/H_i$ are cyclic, and thus abelian. Let consider $$\pi: G\longrightarrow G/H_i,$$
defined by $\pi(g)=gH_i$. Take an element of $[G,G]=\left<ghg^{-1}h^{-1}\mid g,h\in G\right>$. You have that
$$\pi(ghg^{-1}h^{-1})=\pi(g)\pi(h)\pi(g^{-1})\pi(h^{-1})\underset{G/H_i\ cyclic}{=}H_i$$
and thus and thus $[G,G]\leq H_i$, and since $H_1\cap H_2=\{1\}$, we get $[G,G]=\{1\}$. Therefore $G=G/[G:G]$ is abelian.

Comment: Why does $h_1 h_2 = h_2 h_1$ ?

Comment: @lhf: I completed my proof.

Comment: But you haven't shown that the $\langle h_i \rangle$ are normal in $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I will not do all the work ;-) But I agree, it's not the easiest part.

Comment: btw $k_4$ is abelian not cyclic

Comment: This is a very unclear proof. There is too many jumping to conclusions and none of the fillers are well referenced. Also, the proof is not even complete.

Comment: @donaastor: I would say that it's an exercise of second years bachelor. So, each step that you feel as "jumping to conclusion" is a good exercise to progress. None step need references since there are none hard step, and I think that you can find a complete proof with all details in any book of introduction to group theory. So, feel free to check them your self if this is a very unclear proof ;-) However, the aim of the MSE is not to provide proofs with all details but rather helping student to find solutions by them self. So, see it as a Hint if you are not satisfied by my answer ;-)

Comment: @Surb I understand and agree. But what is the point of your post being an answer then? In textbooks you would mostly find proofs using lemmas that the OP mentioned, so it's not the way to go. I know a proof, but using those lemmas, and your proof was still unclear to me. So, from this perspective, what is the point of your post? You have to be clear about which lemmas you are assuming to be known before you leave holes in your proof. Otherwise, we can end in logical loops. This post is fine for a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I do not agree that the answer I provided should be a comment. Moreover, there are too many characters in my answer to put it as a comment (a comment can't exceed 600 characters). Anyway, at the end it is not so important, and if I'm not mistaken, the OP accepted it as his favorite answer. So, I guess that it helped him enough to solve his exercise... 6 years ago ;-)

Comment: @Surb The OP is just the first person to have asked the question. He is not the god of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a non-cyclic group of order $p^2$ with identity element $e$, and let $g,h\in G$ of order $p$ such that $\langle g\rangle\cap \langle h \rangle = \{e\}$. Assume by way of contradiction that $g$ and $h$ do not commute. I claim that $ghg^{-1}$ cannot be a power of $h^k$ of $h$, for if it were, then one calculates that $g^rhg^{-r} = h^{k^r}$ for all $r$, and then $g^{p-1}hg^{1-p} = h^{k^{p-1}}$, which is equal to $h$ by Fermat. This would imply $g^{-1}h=hg^{-1}$ and now $gh=hg$, contradiction.

So $\langle h\rangle$ and $\langle ghg^{-1}\rangle$ are distinct subgroups of order $p$, and the distinct cosets of $\langle ghg^{-1}\rangle$ in $G$ are $\langle ghg^{-1}\rangle, h\langle ghg^{-1}\rangle, h^2\langle ghg^{-1}\rangle, \dots, h^{p-1}\langle ghg^{-1}\rangle$. Therefore $g^{-1}$ lies in some $h^k\langle ghg^{-1}\rangle$, so $g^{-1}=h^kgh^{\ell}g^{-1}$ for some $\ell$. Then $e=h^kgh^{\ell}$ and $g=h^{-k-\ell}$, contradicting that $\langle g \rangle$ and $\langle h \rangle$ intersect trivially.

Well, now we are done: $g$ and $h$ commute, so the mapping from $\mathbb Z_p\times \mathbb Z_p$ to $G$ taking $(a,b)$ to $g^ah^b$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Now for something completely different (using representation theory over $\mathbb{C}$)...

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^2$. Let $Irr(G)$ be its set of complex irreducible characters. Note that the principal character $1_G \in Irr(G)$. Since $|G|=p^2=\sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)}\chi(1)^2=1 + \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)-\{1_G\}}\chi(1)^2$, and for all $\chi \in Irr(G)$: $\chi(1) \mid p^2$, it follows that *all* $\chi$ must be linear, which is equivalent to $G$ being abelian.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am referencing a solution given on Aryaman Maithani's github page. These steps can lead the proof straight forwardly and they are:

Firstly, use the first lemma you mentioned to conclude that $Z(G)$ is of order $p$ or $p^2$. The latter case is trivial by the definition of the center. In the former case, take an element $x$ from $G\setminus Z(G)$ and consider all the elements of $G$ that commute to $x$, name that set $H$. Prove that this set $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Because $x\in H$ we have that $Z(G)$ is a proper subset of $H$. Then, $H$ is a proper subset of $G$ because $x$ isn't in $Z(G)$. Now the order of $H$ must be strictly between $p$ and $p^2$ and must divide $p^2$. This is obviously impossible and that is the contradiction for the former case.

Answer (score 0):

We use the fact that the center of any $p-$group is non-trivial (this uses the class equation). Since the order of $G$ is $p^2$, by LaGrange's theorem as $Z(G) \leq G$, we have that either (as $Z(G) \neq \{e\}$) $\vert Z(G) \vert=p$ or $p^2$. If $\vert Z(G) \vert = p^2$, then $Z(G)=G$ and $G$ is abelian. Suppose then that $\vert Z(G) \vert = p$. Then $Z(G) \varsubsetneq G$ and $G$ is non-abelian. Then $\vert G/ Z(G) \vert = \frac{p^2}{p}=p$, then
$$G/Z(G) \cong \Bbb{Z} / p \Bbb{Z}.$$
And we know $\Bbb{Z} / p \Bbb{Z}$ is cyclic hence $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic thus $G$ is abelian (fact that $G$ is abelian iff $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic), contradiction as $G \neq Z(G)$, thus $Z(G)$ has order $p^2$ hence $Z(G)=G$ forcing $G$ to be abelian.